# Delete any string in front of first <br> appears, and any string after the last <br> shows

Tags: php

Original:

```
Aaron Wind<br/>45 Civic Drive<br/>Greensborough VIC 3088<br/>Australia<br/>‎0450111222
```

Goal:

```
45 Civic Drive<br/>Greensborough VIC 3088<br/>Australia
```

I found it difficult to archive this by using PHP.

Comment: Explode by br, remove items, implode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$s = 'Aaron Wind<br/>45 Civic Drive<br/>Greensborough VIC 3088<br/>Australia<br/>‎0450111222';
// explode your string by `<br/>`
$parts = explode('<br/>', $s);
// remove first and last items
$parts = array_slice($parts, 1, -1);
// implode by `<br/>`
echo implode('<br/>', $parts);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this and let me know by accepting the answer if it works and using of-course the triangle hhh :-)

```
<?php
    $string="Aaron Wind<br/>45 Civic Drive<br/>Greensborough VIC 3088<br/>Australia<br/>‎0450111222";
    $start=stripos($string,"<br/>")+5;
    $last=strrpos($string,"<br/>");
    $newstring=substr($string,$start,$last);
    echo "$newstring";
?>
```

Comment: @user3783243 i have updated the answer i thought he only needed for the strings that have this property strictly. thanks for the comment.